# Find matching couples to maximize global happiness

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matching

A belated Valentines day question for you all:

Suppose we have M men an W women, and they are all heterosexual.  We have a (MxW) matrix A where `A[m, w]` quantifies how happy the couple `(m, w)` would be if married.

How can we pair the couples so that the global maximum happiness is achieved?  (ie I'm looking to produce a length `min(M, W)` array of 2-tuples identifying who should be paired up, such that `sum(A[m, w] for m, w in couples)` is maximized, and each `m` and each `w` is only used once.

Note 1: Ideally I'm looking for a fast numpy implementation, but that's kind of secondary to finding the right algorithm.
Note 2: This is similar, but not the same as the [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), where you specify each person's ranked preferences instead of a happiness value.

Comment: How about you try something first?

Comment: Is it not normal to ask questions like this here?

Comment: The short answer is no. Well it happens a lot, but it's not good. See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Peter: SO is for questions regarding problems for which you have already partial solutions. In you case, this is more like a problem for [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Note that from your question, it looks like you have a [linear assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture10.pdf

Comment: Google search terms: `maximum weight bipartite matching`

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to the commenters for pointing out that this is the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and is usually described in terms of workers and jobs.

Scipy has [a function that solves it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) using the Hungarian Algorithm.